# SwiftUI MacOS - Set NSToolbar color

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nstoolbar

### How can I change the background of the toolbar in a window?

I'm working with SwiftUI for MacOS (including App Lifecycle).

I have tried changing the window's background color, but it does not affect the toolbar

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    ...
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSApp.mainWindow?.backgroundColor = .red //not affecting the toolbar
    }
}
```

Also, I looked at these:

- [Set background image NSToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084699/set-background-image-nstoolbar)
- [How to change NSToolBar background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371550/how-to-change-nstoolbar-background-color)

It frustrating that there are no standard APIs for that simple customization.

Comment: I mean the toolbar itself. I didn't use it in the example because there is no API like `window.toolbar.backgroundColor`

Comment: Nope, the link is a question about the *sidebar*, and I'm struggling with the Toolbar.
Secondly, the answer there is using the older AppDelegate (not the SwiftUI lifecycle) which is not that relevant anymore.

Comment: Is NSApp.mainWindow nil? Also do you have System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency checked?

Comment: The `mainWindow` is not nil. The background color affect the rest of the window (but not the toolbar)